# À la recherche d'une expression qui veut dire "to not have a dog in this fight"

Tags: grammaire, expressions, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

Bonjour,

Je suis actuellement à la recherche d'une expression à peu près équivalente à

> I don't have a dog in this fight. [1]

Je trouve (et là j'ai peut-être tort) que les expressions comme

> Ça m'est égal, ça ne me regarde pas, je m'en fiche/fous

n'expriment pas ce que je veux. Plus précisément, je trouve que les expressions ci-dessous sont un peu plus sévères/dures/sèches que ce que j'entends dans "not have a dog in this fight".

Voici un exemple où j'aimerais bien l'utiliser:

> Do as you wish, I don't really have a dog in this fight, I just wanted to let you know about [something].

Donc, que mettriez-vous à sa place ici ?

[1] https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/no+dog+in+this+fight.html

Comment: Peut-être que *je ne me sens pas concerné*  est un peu moins sec ? Mais *ça ne me regarde pas* / *ce n'est pas mes affaires* semblent plus proches de l'expression anglaise.

Comment: "ça m'est égal" ou "peu m'importe" sont relativement neutres. Mais, quelle que soit la formulation, faire comprendre à quelqu'un que "ceci n'est pas mon problème" sera souvent mal perçu. Sauf à dire, "je ne voudrais pas m'en méler" (I'd rather not get involved) qui indiquera que vous n'êtes pas intrusif.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il n'y a pas d'équivalent exact, cela dépend énormément du contexte.

Pour utiliser sa propre neutralité comme argument :

> Je ne suis pas de parti pris

> Je suis neutre dans cette histoire

> Je n'ai pas d'intérêt particulier dans cette affaire

*(donc je peux dire impartialement que...)*

Pour exprimer le recul ou l'indifférence par rapport à un conflit externe :

> Je suis en-dehors de tout ça

> Leur querelle ne me concerne pas

> Je ne prends pas position dans ce débat

Pour exprimer l'indifférence vis-à-vis d'une partie d'un problème :

> (Fais comme tu veux), je n'ai pas d'avis tranché sur X (mais Y...)

On peut aussi adapter des expressions imagées existantes selon le contexte :

> Il n'a pas de pions sur cet échiquier

> Il n'a pas de fauteuil à la table de paris

> Je laisse à d'autres de miser sur un cheval dans cette course

Comment: Est-ce que "il faut choisir ses combats/batailles" transporte le même sens ? J'aime la similarité du thème avec l'expression anglophone.

Comment: A mon avis c'est légèrement différent. "Il faut choisir ses batailles" implique qu'on a misé sur une autre bataille, ce qui n'est pas toujours le cas avec *not have a dog in this fight*.

Answer (score 8):

Une expression imagée approximative :

> Ce ne sont pas mes oignons

Answer (score 4):

La traduction suivante n'est pas un équivalent imagé, ce qui serait idéal puisque « I don't have a dog… » est une image, mais c'est une traduction exacte.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_a_dog_in_this_fight)) (Sens figuré) Avoir un intérêt quelconque dans cette affaire.

Il est préférable de dire « avoir un/n'avoir aucun intérêt dans cette affaire » : (TLFi : « a) Un/une + subst. + quelconque. N'importe quel(le). ») ; le sens serait qu'un intérêt qui n'est pas n'importe lequel est bien un intérêt du locuteur.

- Do as you wish, I don't really have a dog in this fight, I just wanted to let you know about [something].
- Faites comme vous l'entendez, je n'ai aucun intérêt dans cette querelle, je voulais seulement vous dire [qqc]

Answer (score 4):

> Je ne suis pas [partie](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/partie/58037) prenante (dans qqch.).

Sans être une traduction exacte, au figuré avec la négative, *ne pas être directement impliqué* dans quelque chose. Un peu différent sans la négation, c'est le *stake(holder)/to have (a/no) stake in*, mais je trouve que ça rejoint l'expression pour éviter l'idée d'indifférence etc.

Comment: Langage qui ne correspond pas du tout au contexte ; « partie prenante » est un terme du langage des affaires, de la politique, de l'administration ; on va trouver ça pompeux dans les contextes courants (-1). https://www.google.com/search?q=%22partie%20prenante%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

Comment: @LPH La crtique est plutôt valide. Mais note l'exemple sur macmillan : _t’s worth noting that these corporations have a dog in the health care fight._ Ton emploi de 2PL ne convient pas au contexte non plus ; je ne peux retirer le vote que je t'ai donné cependant pour le souligner.